# A depict of a cyclic group with a normal group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, cyclic-groups

If $G$ is a group, $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, $[G:H]=k,{\rm ord}_G(a)=n,a\in G,|\langle a\rangle\cap H|=m,$ prove: The term of $\langle a\rangle$ in $G/H$ is $\frac{n}{m}$.

I have some thoughts but to be honest I do not think I solve it completely.

First, we can prove that: $H\cap\langle a\rangle\unlhd G\cap\langle a\rangle$. It's easy and trivial.

Then attention to $[(\langle a\rangle\cap G)\backslash(\langle a\rangle\cap H]=[(\langle a\rangle\cap G):(\langle a\rangle\cap H]=\frac{|\langle a\rangle\cap G|}{|\langle a\rangle\cap H|}$.

So we can prove that $\langle a\rangle \cap (G\backslash H)= (\langle a \rangle \cap G)\backslash(\langle a \rangle\cap H)$.

But I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Use `$\langle a\rangle$` for $\langle a\rangle$.

Comment: $\langle a\rangle$ is not a coset of $H$, so what does "${\rm ord}_{G/H}(\langle a\rangle)=\frac{m}{n}$" mean?

Comment: Moreover, $m<n$ and hence $\frac{m}{n}$ is not even an integer.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. I have edited the context for another time.

Comment: What is "the term"? Also, $\langle a \rangle$ is not a subset of $G/H$. What does a barcketed set indicate? $(\langle a \rangle \cap G)\setminus (\langle a\rangle \cap H)$ is just a set, so what does it mean when you enclose it with brackets? I have a hard time understanding what is in this post.

Comment: And as preumably $a\in G$, then $\langle a \rangle \cap G = \langle a \rangle$. So why all those intersections?